# Post request not working

Tags: post, titanium, appcelerator

i've got an android app and a really simple web service that make an insert in a DB with 3 values.

the titanium code is most like the example given on the docs

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function(e) {};

xhr.open('POST','http://www.micheleantonaci.altervista.org/test/foobar.php');
xhr.send({
"latitude":00100,
"longitude":10000,
"type":'From Nexus'
});
```

and the web service is just

```
<?php       
   $con=mysql_connect('http://www.micheleantonaci.altervista.org/','***','***');
   mysql_select_db('***',$con);
   if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{  
    $latitude=$_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude=$_POST['longitude'];
    $kind=$_POST['type'];

    $sql="insert into foobar (latitude,longitude,type) values ('$latitude','$longitude','$kind')";
    $res=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}
?>
```

now, when i try the webservice giving the values with the browser it works good, but with the app I get no results at all, any suggestions? tha app doesn't crash or log any error

Comment: Same did i experience. So, eventually i converted to GET request.

Comment: but it's a kinda hard thing when you need to send images, that should be my next step :V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is right, the problem was on the framework itself, at that day the post method wasn't working.
Nowadays it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You must use PHP function `json_decode` to get values.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the header like this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

You should also do a var_dump($_POST) in your PHP to see what's in it, not sure you'll get your stuff in separated variables...

Answer (score 0):

When I see a problem like this, I setup 'Charles' or a similar proxy and have the device send it's request through the proxy.  Then you can see if the device is send what is expected.

You could also try

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```